# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Today I was really confused detecting what I thought to be a "bug" but it was something about EF Database creating **logic\lifetime** I really didn't know. Could you explain this moment more deeply? Or where can I read about it?

**1. There is a model**
`

```
public class ExpertMarksDefinition
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SpecialtyAcronym { get; set; }
        public string ExpertName { get; set; }
        public string ExpertPosition { get; set; }

        public double Sensory { get; set; }
        public double Intuition { get; set; }
        //A lot of fields below...
}
```

**2. There are a context and initializer (Seed)**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SpecialtyDefenition> Specialties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExpertMarksDefinition> Marks {get;set;}
    ...
}
public class ApplicationDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    private DataInitializer initializer;
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        initializer = new DataInitializer();
        List<ExpertMarksDefinition> marks = initializer.GetMarks();
        context.Marks.AddRange(marks);
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

And the App_Start contains

```
Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
```

Database should be initialized in App_Data folder, but folder was empty.
Even in Controller there was an initialization of **ApplicationDbContext** in the constructor.

```
public BayesCalculationController(){ _db = new ApplicationDbContext(); }
```

After 1 hour of mad searching of "bug" I just tried to send data to View.

```
@model IEnumerable<ExpertMarksDefinition>
@foreach(var e in Model){ <p>@e.ExpertName</p>}
```

And all worked! EF created .mdf file in App_Data. 
I was thinking that if **Database.SetInitializer** called in **App_Start** then **Seed** should do the same.
I understand that it happened because of my lack knowledge of how EF and ASP.NET MVC works in the inner level. 
So, could you explain me or just give a link where I can learn about why it works in such way?

Comment: EF is lazy-initialised. It does not access DB until it actually needs it. Call `dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);` to force the initialisation